# Simple set proof (is it right?)

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

**Statement:**  $A\cup B = A\cap B \iff A=B$

**Proof:** For the converse assume that $A=B$. We need to show that $A\cup B \subseteq A\cap B$ and $A\cap B \subseteq A\cup B$. First we show that $A\cup B \subseteq A\cap B$. Let $x \in A \cup B$, then $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. Since $A=B$ it follows that $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. So $x \in A\cap B$ and thus $A\cup B \subseteq A\cap B$. Now for the other way around. Let $x \in A\cap B$, then $x \in A$ and $x\in B$. So $x \in A\cup B$ (because it still holds when $x \in A$ and $x \in B$). Thus $A\cap B \subseteq A\cup B$ and now we have proved that $A\cup B = A\cap B$.

Assume that $A\cup B = A\cap B$. We need to show that $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$.
First we show that $A\subseteq B$. Let $x \in A$ , then $x \in A \cup B$. Since $A\cup B=A\cap B$ it follows that $x \in A\cap B$. So $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. Thus $A\subseteq B$. The other way is similar. *End of proof.*

It feels like the converse proof is a bit.. not perfect/right. Can someone verify? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I edited the proof. Is it (more) correct now?

Comment: Neither direction is correct. Try starting out with the definition, i.e. to show a set equality you want to show two inclusions.

Comment: For Converse, first assume that $A=B$, now you need to prove $A \cup B=A \cap B$. To prove that you need to show $x \in A \cup B \Rightarrow x \in A \cap B$ and vice versa. Follow the same for other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assume $A = B$, you want to show $A\cup B = A\cap B$. That means you start with an $x\in A\cup B$ and show that $x\in A\cap B$, and vice versa. What you have done is to assume that $A = B$ and then start with $x\in A$. That will not lead where you want it to lead.

Assume $A= B$, and let $x\in A\cup B$. By definition of $\cup$ we have $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. However, we can't have one without the other, as $A = B$. Thus we must have $x\in A$ *and* $x\in B$, which gives us $x\in A\cap B$. This shows $A\cup B\subseteq A\cap B$. For $A\cap B\subseteq A\cup B$, we don't need the assumption at all; this is always true: Take $x\in A\cap B$. By definition of $\cup$ we have $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. By basic logic, it must then be true that $x\in A$ *or* $x\in B$, which gives us $x\in A\cup B$.

This shows that $A = B\implies A\cup B = A\cap B$. The other implication is somewhat similar. Note that the crucial part of assuming $A\cup B = A\cap B$ is the inclusion $A\cup B\subseteq A\cap B$, as the other inclusion is always true, and thus not something special.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! That helped me very much. Can you check if my proof of the other implication is correct? - im editing and writing it atm-

Comment: @Wouter You have the same issue there. You're assuming $A\cup B = A\cap B$, which is fine. Using that assumption you want to show that $A = B$. However, you begin with $x\in A\cup B$. That's not how a proof of $A = B$ will start.

Comment: I updated my post now. I didn't want to send my previous comment (was still editing the post).

Comment: @Wouter It looks much better now. Good job!

Comment: Thank you! Is the proof of the implication the other way around (where i assume $A\cup B=A\cap B$) correct?

Comment: @Wouter Yes, that part looks good too.

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Wouter You can also proof $(A\cap B)=(A\cup B)\rightarrow A=B$ by contradiction. Assume that antecedent holds and conclusion doesn't, then show that the union of two sets is not a subset of their intersection.

Comment: @anfauglit That proof is made easier if you just make it contrapositive rather than contradiction. No need to assume the antecedent and then derive the negation of the antecedent and then claim contradiction when you can just derive the negation of the antecedent (all the while assuming the negation of the conclusion, of course). This removes a layer of abstraction, and doesn't change the meat of the proof in the slightest.

Comment: @Arthur Have to agree that this way the proof looks more cleaner .

Answer (score 2):

Assume A = B.  Then
A $\cup$ B = A $\cup$ A = A = A $\cap$ A = A $\cap$ B.

Conversely:
A subset A $\cup$ B = A $\cap$ B subset B;
In a like fashion B subset A.